# Конфликт обратного доступа при создании структуры базы

Tags: python, django

Создаю 2 модели Кошелек (Wallet) и Заказ (Order). В заказе есть "кошелек откуда" и "кошелек куда". Отношение один ко многим.

```
    class Wallet(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=False)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)

        class Meta:
            ordering=('name',)
            verbose_name = 'wallet'
            verbose_name_plural = 'wallets'

        def str(self):
            return self.name

    class Order(models.Model):
        number = models.CharField(max_length=36, db_index=True)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        fromwallet = models.ForeignKey('Wallet', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        fromsum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
        towallet = models.ForeignKey('Wallet', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        tosum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ('number',)
            index_together = (('id', 'number'),)
            verbose_name = 'order'
            verbose_name_plural = 'orders'

        def str(self):
            return self.number
```

При попытке создания из моделей структуры базы данных: python manage.py makemigrations
Возникает ошибка:

```
    SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

    ERRORS:
    shop.Order.fromwallet: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Order.fromwallet' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Order.towallet'.
            HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Order.fromwallet' or 'Order.towallet'.
    shop.Order.towallet: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Order.towallet' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Order.fromwallet'.
            HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Order.towallet' or 'Order.fromwallet'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `related_name` атрибут полям со связью `ForeignKey`:

*Например:*

```py
...
class Order(models.Model):
    fromwallet = models.ForeignKey('Wallet', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fromwallet')
    towallet = models.ForeignKey('Wallet', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='towallet')
    ...
```